# Redirect a user if on mobile device (not tablet) but provide back link

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, mobile, back

This is completely new to me and haven't a clue what I'm doing so I would really prefer a simple to implement solution (if it exists).

I need to redirect users who visit www.domain.co.uk (hosted on Wordpress) on mobile devices (not tablets) to a specific page like this (with WP's permalinks):

www.domain.co.uk/mobile-home

From that mobile page, I also need to provide a link back to the desktop homepage on the same domain, like this:

www.domain.co.uk/desktop-home

I had been playing with code similar to this in my header.php file:

```
<script>if( 'ontouchstart' in window ) window.location = 'mobile.html';</script>
```

but it will just redirect a mobile user back to the mobile version if I link directly to the desktop page. How can I get the functionality I require?

**UPDATE**

Ok, my first step is to direct my mobile visitors to the mobile page. So I have pasted the following code into my page template of the homepage for my website and tested seems to work. I've put it just beneath the opening 'body' tag:

```
<script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
window.location = "176.32.230.17/domain.co.uk/m";
}
</script>
```

Now I'm having trouble linking back to the homepage using the below code. It takes me back to the hompage but the homepage has the code above detecting the device and keeps taking me back to the mobile site. Am I putting the device detection in the right place?:

```
<a href="http://176.32.230.17/domain.co.uk/?ref=desktop">Link back to desktop website</a>
```

Comment: have your "back" link do a bit of javascript to set a cookie which sets their site type preference, and only do the redirect if the cookie's not present or they're hitting the "other" site type.

Comment: @MarcB Could you give an example of how I would do this? Also if the user was on the mobile device, clicked to go to the desktop, would they be able to get back to the mobile version?

Comment: You can't differ between tablet and mobile device - thats not reliable possbile. If you want to know, if you are on a mobile device you can check the user agent for the most common mobile browsers or os

Comment: @Philipp Thanks but as I said in my question, is this simple to achieve? I don't really know how to go about doing what you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from using @Phillip's code I have managed to come up with a complete solution to my question.

I place the following JS in my header.php template to detect if user agent is a mobile device, if is then perform another check to see if the URL contains the hashtag '#desktop', if it does, do nothing and keep user on desktop version. If it doesn't then redirect to mobile website:

**JS**

```
<script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {

if(window.location.hash == "#desktop"){
    // Stay on desktop website
} else {
    window.location = "http://www.domain.co.uk/m";
}

}
</script>
```

Then to complete the loop, add a link on the mobile site that adds the hashtag '#desktop' to the URL ensuring they don't get redirected back to the mobile version automatically:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.co.uk/#desktop">View desktop site</a>
```

Comment: And you will be missing Firefox OS with this one and some Opera browsers. `/mobi/i`  to catch mobile lowercase substrings.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect a mobile browser with the user agent property of `navigator` and redirect the visitor to the mobile page. Differ between tablet and mobile isn't reliable possible(i.E. is the Galaxy Note a tablet or mobile?)

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    window.location = "yourmobileurl.com/?ref=desktop";
}
```

On the server you can check the ref var for desktop and show the visitor a link to get back and store the choice in a session

Comment: With this solution are you saying that the ref part of the URL can change depending on the server? Or can I just manually add it to the URL and it will work

Comment: I've updated my question with progress. I can't seem to successfully link back to the desktop version of my website, any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
```

Please ref this link :http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/

It explains how to detect device using javascript

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to have the link back to desktop version have a url parameter, and only forward from desktop to mobile when that parameter isn't set.

As for detecting the device, you have to read the user-agent and provide logic.  [Here's a link to detect iPad and iPhone](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/toolbox/article.php/3888106/How-Can-I-Detect-the-iPhone--iPads-User-Agent.htm).  Similar user agents apply to others.  There is no silver bullet to identify a tablet.

You can identify most specific devices by learning what their user agent returns, but this is always open to being changed, and you would have to do this for every possible tablet.

As for the parameter solution, that seems straight-forward.  You would link to http://www.mywebpage.com/MyDesktopHome?forwardToMobile=no.  Otherwise you could store that in either the session or cookie, depending on how long you want to persist it.

Comment: Thanks but I'm confused a little. Could you show me an example of what you mean taking into account my need to only redirect mobile devices and not tablets?